# How do I deploy a Google VM instance with local files copied onto it with Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I need to deploy a compute VM with some code on it that is triggered on startup with Terraform.

After trying to clone repositories in the startup script (too complex due to difficult authentication with private remote), I decided to try and simply copy the code onto the VM using Terraform.

I came across file provisioner but I can't at all figure out how to automatically add the files to the VM with it. It seems as if it needs me to provide connection details.

Is there a way of doing this that is simpler? Or can anyone explain how to use the provisioner correctly.

Comment: This would be more easily accomplished by deploying a custom image with the application installed and configured.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard what google cloud product what that run inside? I need to keep state, so Cloud Run probably wouldn't be the way forward unless I'm mistaken. Is there a way to create this for Compute Engine?

Comment: 1) Terraform is not the best product for your use case. You need to launch the instance, wait for the startup to complete, and then connect using SSH to copy files to the instance. Terraform has no built-in method to determine whether the VM has completed its startup. You would have to write scripts to do those features. 2) You might be able to use a VM startup script to download files from Google Cloud Storage. Terraform does support specifying GCE startup scripts.

Comment: John is right. Terraform is the infra part. Avoid to mix application part with it. Deploy your VM with terraform and then SCP the file in it. Or copy the file on GCS, and use terraform to deploy your VM with a startup script that point to GCS. In both case, you need 2 steps (in your Ci/CD pipeline for instance)